# Can you use a flex (spider) coupler as a dog clutch in a motorbike/atv/go kart/lawn mower like setting?

Tags: motorcycle, transmission, power, atv

My question is simple: I want to make a dog clutch system for a wakeboarding cable system and was wondering if a flex (spider) coupler could used?  The power, velocity, torque is similar to a go kart / lawn mower, atv etc.

Dog clutch:

[image]

Flex Spider Coupler (the one with a nylon/plastic insert)

[image]

Background: I am working on a unique wakeboarding cable system design which goes forward and backwards at the same speed.  The idea is to build a hybrid winch/cable 2.0 system which uses a 6.5 HP 3600 RPM engine to pull a 200 pound person 30 km/h (spool is 0.3 m radius). Ideally a system would have a neutral, forward and reverse, but forward and reverse alone would also be acceptable (with a skilled operator).

I can easily gear down to get the required speed/torque but I currently can not find a transmission/gear box which offers reverse at the same or similar speed ratioto forward.  The two options I found are a:

1/ TAV (Torque-A-Verter) Style Reverse Gearbox which has a 1:1.3 forward, 1:2.6 reverse and a neutral

2/ Planetary reverse gearbox which has a 1:1 forward, 1:1.5 reverse and no neutral.

If this is not possible, I would also be interested in alternative solutions.

Comment: So the input shaft will have one shaft inside the other? It could work, ONLY if both shafts are stationary (relative or total) when selecting a gear otherwise you will need a clutch of some sort.

Comment: Alsdo posted here : https://engineering.stackexchange.com/q/26717/10902

Comment: Hi Solar Mike, yes that makes sense.  My design will have 2 output shafts , so that's not an issue (one will be stationary).  The real question is if the flex spider coupler can handle the load .